# Redux - should I get product details from state or api call?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a react and redux app, I have all the products of my user fetched and stored in the state when the user first logs in and get to the homepage. The user can then see some individual page for his products and potentially edit things in there.

So on the details page I have the possibility to use the already stored product from the list in the state. It avoids needing to make another api call, and as I understood it is the "react way". It's fast and efficient.

But I also see drawbacks to this:

- if the user directly access the url of hi.com/product/1 the store hasn't been populated with his products data, and then it's unavailable. What to do then? Conditionally load in the store the data for the current product? Redirect to the home page? Sounds messy.
- It forces the system to load details for each products initially. It's fine if there are not too much products, but it sounds bad if there are a lot. More data to send through the network, and more data to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this specific condition you can add Content Guard (or Route Guard) for your routes, which specifically check whether your required data is present in Redux states or not.

There is one nice Library you can use here [react-router-guards](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-guards)

or You can always make your own logical functional component that will manage your routes and essential API calls according to your pages

For Example

If you are directly visiting hi.com/product/1

**1) When you are using react-router-guards**

```
const requireStates = (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta.auth) {
    if (getIsLoggedIn()) {
      let actualPath = to.location.pathname.split("/");
      if(actualPath[1] === "product") {
       if(isProductAPIDataPresent)// here check if redux state have that particular data present
        {
          next();
        } else {
           fetch(); // get Product API data 
           store(); // store it in redux states
           next();
        }
      } else {
           next();
      }
    }
    next.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <GuardProvider guards={[requireStates]} loading={Loading} error={NotFound}>
      <Switch>
        <GuardedRoute path="/product/:productID" exact component={Product} meta={{ auth: true }} />
        <GuardedRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} meta={{ auth: true }} />
        <GuardedRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </GuardProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**2) And when you want to build your own functional logic** (you can just make one functional component that will return some essential true false cases)

```
   const requireStates = (tprops) => {
             let next = {
               isAllowed: true,
               newLocation: "/",
             }
              if (props.meta.auth) {
                if (getIsLoggedIn()) {
                  let actualPath = props.location.pathname.split("/");
                  if(actualPath[1] === "product") {
                    if(isProductAPIDataPresent)// here check if redux state have that particular data present
                    {
                      return next;
                    } else {
                       fetch(); // get Product API data 
                       store(); // store it in redux states
                       return next;
                    }
                 } else {
                  return next;
                }
                
       
                next.isAllowed = false;
                next.newLocation = "/login"
                return next;
              } else {
                return next;
              }
            };
```

You also need to make one Parent Component (Common For all Route it can be Layout component)  which will render before proceeding with that particular route component or child component

So in that Parent component, you can inject the above logic like

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await requireStates(this.props).then((result) => {
      if (!result.isAllowed) {
        window.location.replace(result.newLocation);
      }
    });
  };
```

Note*: For the second solution there could be numerous way you can achieve your required goal

Comment: Very interesting and detailed answer, thanks! What about the second point in my questions, isn't that a performace issue to send over lots of data I potentially won't need?

Comment: Here I am considering you have stored data directly in a single redux state, when you have lots of data or might a case of deeply nested data, you will face performance issues to fetch a particular data from it (you can solve this by using various efficient Algorithms). So in this particular case scenario, I have personally used IndexDB to store and manage my states. IndexDB helps to store your data with indexing and later on, you can fetch it efficiently and you can also secure this storage with various methods for data safety. You can handle your case considering your data complexity.